# hudson netbeans project build

Tags: netbeans, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I want to start a job in Hudson to build my netbeans web project.
While I can run `ant dist` in my project directory successfully my hudson task throws following error after updating(pulling) data in its own workspace

```
-init-debug-args:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.hudson\jobs\Scribe\workspace\nbproject\build-impl.xml:485: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "${platforms.JDK_1.6_64_Bit_.home}\bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 23 more

Total time: 0 seconds
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: Scribe #12 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

My build command in hudson looks like following

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29-R28.2.2-4.1.0\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29-R28.2.2-4.1.0
I:\Developement\libs\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin\ant -Dj2ee.server.home=E:\eClinicalWorks\tomcat6 dist
```

Surprisingly `ant` is not recognized from the "PATH" variable rather I have to give absolute path

build-impl.xml can be found here http://cynosuredev.com/build-impl.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by copying java options from netbeans private folder which never gets commited:)